# In a card style layout, do pin/unpin have the same meaning to the user as hide/unhide?

Tags: layout, cards, catalog

I'm working on a card layout, where the user should have activities, such as pin / unpin a card, and hide / unhide a card. The first action can be done on a catalog page, where the user can choose cards they want to add to their page. Also the user can unpin a card from their page in an edit mode.

The question is: do I really need hide / unhide a card on the user's page? Or pin / unpin option is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question that needs an answer first; why would the user hide a card from the Users page in the first place - what is the purpose/advantage for the user?

I feel you're talking about simple add/remove functionality. Pin a card equals "add", while now you're looking for a way to offer "delete" as well.

If this is the case, I'd simply offer the user a way to delete the card... not hiding, or unpinning, which might confuse the user. Add/delete makes sense enough.